# Connecting To MySql Database Through C# For Login

Tags: c#, mysql

I have searched everywhere for this and I cannot find a solution.

Basically. I have already created my MySQL database. I have already referenced the MySQL Connector into my project. I can connect, but it says "Host: {ip address} is not allowed to connect to my MySQL server". I fixed this by allowing remote connections from everywhere, but I heard it is a dangerous that to do.

I am simply trying to make my software users login before they can use the software (and maybe other stuff... the point is that I am trying to use MySQL to connect to my .NET application). Is it safe to allow mysql connections from any IP address? If someone somehow reversed engineered my code, they will have access to my database credentials.

Is there any other solution?

Comment: Have you looked into web services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sure many of us will agree on not to write DB connection string in your application which you will give to end user.

Also it is risky to all connection from any IP to DB.

The best way is to create WEB SERVICE and call it to authenticate user and it will save you from both;

1. No need to provide connection string in application.
2. As your web service will run on same PC or any other single PC so no need to allow remote    connection from all IP.